# Referencing and printing table entries in main body

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have a table with numbers and I would like to reference a specific number in this table by re-producing it in the main body of the text. For example in this table:

```
 \begin{table}[h]\caption{Summary Statistics}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline\hline
 &\textbf{Fraction of Monkeys}\\\hline
{New Construction}&0.006\\
{Preventive Maintenance}&0.275\\
{Resurfacing}&0.291\\
{Road Reconstruction}&0.103\\
{Road Rehabilitation}&0.105\\
{Roadside Facilities}&0.079\\
{Safety}&0.141\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

I would like to be able to write the following sentence in my main body:
"Roadside Facilities appear in **0.079** of monkeys". I would like the bold item to be linked to the table so that any update in the table is immediately reflected in the main text.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hijacking" the `\label`-`\ref` system is fairly easy and can be used in this instance:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savevalue}[2]{\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}\ref{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Summary Statistics}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
    \toprule
    & \textbf{Fraction of Monkeys} \\
    \midrule
    New Construction & 0.006 \\
    Preventive Maintenance & 0.275 \\
    Resurfacing & 0.291 \\
    Road Reconstruction & 0.103 \\
    Road Rehabilitation & 0.105 \\
    Roadside Facilities & \savevalue{0.079}{roadside-facilities} \\
    Safety & 0.141 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Roadside Facilities appear in \textbf{\ref{roadside-facilities}} of monkeys.
\end{document}
```

The idea is to update `\@currentlabel` with the value (or text, or whatever) you want, and immediately `\label` it. Then you can `\ref` it wherever in your document. This combined functionality is offered by `\savevalue{<stuff>}{<label>}`. Of course, since it uses the `\label`-`\ref` system, at least two compiles for the first time is required for references to settle.

[`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) offers some `tabular` flair. If you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) - which highlights certain links - and you want to get rid of this, some more work is required.